# Java Printing Tray Selection Saga

Tags: java, printing, tray

While there are several questions regarding tray selection out there, none of them relate to my problem.

Here's the code I'm using to print:

```
private static void finalPrint(PDDocument pdoc, boolean pbStationary)
    throws BigBangJewelException
{
    PrintService lrefSvc;
    PrinterJob lrefPJob;
    Media lrefMedia;
    HashPrintRequestAttributeSet lobjSet;

    lrefSvc = getPrinter();

    lrefPJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();

    try
    {
        lrefPJob.setPrintService(lrefSvc);
        lrefPJob.setPageable(pdoc);

        lrefMedia = null;
        if ( pbStationary )
            lrefMedia = getTray(lrefSvc);
        if ( lrefMedia != null )
        {
            lobjSet = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
            lobjSet.add(lrefMedia);
            lrefPJob.print(lobjSet);
        }
        else
            lrefPJob.print();
    }
    catch (Throwable e)
    {
        throw new BigBangJewelException(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}

private static PrintService getPrinter()
    throws BigBangJewelException
{
    String lstrPrinter;
    PrintService[] larrServices;
    int i;

    try
    {
        lstrPrinter = (String)Engine.getUserData().get("Printer");

        larrServices = PrinterJob.lookupPrintServices();

        for ( i = 0; i < larrServices.length; i++ )
        {
            if (larrServices[i].getName().indexOf(lstrPrinter) != -1)
                return larrServices[i];
        }
    }
    catch (Throwable e)
    {
        throw new BigBangJewelException(e.getMessage(), e);
    }

    throw new BigBangJewelException("Impressora definida (" + lstrPrinter + ") não encontrada.");
}

private static Media getTray(PrintService prefSvc)
{
    Media[] larrMedia;
    String lstrAux;
    int i;

    larrMedia = (Media[])prefSvc.getSupportedAttributeValues(Media.class, null, null);

    if ( larrMedia == null )
        return null;

    for ( i = 0; i < larrMedia.length; i++ )
    {
        lstrAux = larrMedia[i].toString().toLowerCase();
        if (lstrAux.contains("tray") && lstrAux.contains("3"))
        {
            return larrMedia[i];
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

The baffling thing is, this code *used to work*. The machine had a bunch of Xerox printers defined, and the code would correctly identify the wanted printer, and the wanted tray, and everything worked wonderfully.

Then, one day, overnight, it stopped working. It still finds the right printer, but now, it always prints to tray 1.

The only thing that changed was that an extra HP printer was added to the machine.

I can confirm that the code is finding the tray and sending it to the print job, but it's getting ignored.

Again, there are many questions out there regarding this issue, but my problem is that the code worked well for four years, then stopped working for no apparent reason.

Can anyone shed any light on this subject?

**Edit:** New information: Uninstalling the HP printer made the Xerox printers work right again. Why would installing one driver affect Java's ability to communicate with a different driver?

**Edit 2:** Further information: If we install the HP global printer driver instead of the specific printer driver, everything works correctly. I'll leave the question unanswered to see if anyone can come up with a good explanation before the bounty expires, then I'm going to put this edit in an answer and accept it.

Comment: Logs from exceptions etc can be Your "light" ... this code is almost impossible to test for people from SO

Comment: That's the thing, there are no exceptions. The setting is just silently ignored.

Comment: I like the exception name `BigBangJewelException` but it's quite pointless to do something like this: `throw new BigBangJewelException(e.getMessage(), e);`. Simply omit the first argument.

Comment: What does your debugger say? If debugging is difficult or impossible, you could add some logging code to find out what's happening. (My guess would be that the `getTray()` method started to return `null`- perhaps the expectations about the String contents don't hold?)

Comment: No, you're missing the point. The code works. The tray is selected correctly and sent to the print job correctly. The printer itself is (was) ignoring it. There's additional information in the question.

Comment: First thing I'd check would be if this only happens when printing through the Java API, or it's a problem in general.

Comment: It only happens when printing through the Java API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to our particular situation was to change the printer drivers for the HP printer.

Originally, we had installed the specific driver for the printer in question, which caused this behavior. Installing HP's global driver instead made the problem go away.

Unfortunately, we do not know why. Jens Schauder's answer contains clues as to how to go about finding out.

Answer (score 3):

If I got you question correctly, you the content of `lobjSet` is unchanged, yet it the print result is different, with the new driver installed.

I checked the code for [`PnterJob.print(PrintRequestAttributeSet)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/awt/print/PrinterJob.java#PrinterJob.print%28javax.print.attribute.PrintRequestAttributeSet%29) and was surprised that it completely ignores the attribute set.

So I looked at where the `PrintService` is coming from, the code is a little lengthy, but I guess it interacts somehow with the installed printer drivers to create appropriate instances.  So the new driver changes this, returning a different `PrintService`. There is no way I can tell in what exact way this thing changes, but if you can recreate both scenarios (and it seems you can), it should be fairly easy to use a debugger to find the exact place where the behavior of the code changes.

Comment: This sounds like a good idea, but unfortunately, this is only happening on the production machine, and I have no way of debugging against it. I did take a look at the code you mentioned, and it is indeed lengthy. +1 for taking the time to look at it.

Comment: Well, I don't want this bounty to go to waste, and it doesn't look like anyone is going to come up with anything better, so, have at it. :)